# Exporting Long Text from Access 2016 to Excel 2016 Truncates after 4000 Characters

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-access

I have a table in Access 2016 with long text fields. When I export to Excel 2016 as XLSX with or without formatting, long text fields are getting cut off after 4000 characters.

Comment: Have you examined the cutoff points in the exported text? Perhaps a certain character or character class is causing truncation. Maybe it would be helpful to share a few examples of truncated text (including what is left off).

Comment: Yes. They are cutting off at character 32 (space). I didn't see any pattern. The cell contents doesn't exceed the cell limit.

Comment: Is the space included in the export or omitted?

Comment: Turns out it is not caused by the space character. I am hitting a 4000 character limit on export to Excel even though it's a long text data type in Access. I read 4000 is the limit for short text in Access.

Comment: Please update your question to include this new information: https://superuser.com/posts/1201730/edit

Comment: I believe this Stack Overflow question is about your problem (Long Text is the new name for Memos in Access): http://stackoverflow.com/q/16472608/657668

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, a cell can contain 32,767 characters.  Pasting anything longer results in truncation.

Source: [Excel specifications and limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#ID0EBABAAA=Excel_2016-2013)